# setState is not updating the state, even in its callback react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

here the user_res is updated but not the state, and I have tried binding this function to this also. but same result :(

```
let user_res = usr_vote;
user_res.map((vote)=>{
  if(vote.id==dat_id){
    vote.status = stats
  }
})
console.log("update user response:",user_res)
this.setState({user_response:user_res},()=>{
  console.log("but this is not uodating : ",this.state.user_response)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think even `user_res` is updating. `map` doesn't update the original variable. You need to assign the value of `.map` to something.

```
user_res = user_res.map((vote)=>{
            if(vote.id==dat_id){
                return {...vote, status: stats}
            } else {return vote}
        })
```

Comment: No, it is updating, and log is showing it, and I also used forEach for it. same result :(

Answer (score 2):

If you check [documentation form `Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you will see that `map` doesn't modify the original array, it returns a new array with the modified items.

> The `map()` method **creates a new array** with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

So with that information you can modify your code accordingly,

```
// create a new array with the modified items
let user_res = usr_vote.map((vote) => {
  if(vote.id == dat_id){
    vote.status = stats
  }
});
// update state with the new array
this.setState({user_response:user_res},()=>{
  console.log("but this is not uodating : ",this.state.user_response)
});
```

**PS:** `stats` is not defined anywhere in your snippet. If you are not defining it somewhere in your code that your shared snippet doesn't contain, it is OK but otherwise you need to fix that part too.